# Need help identifying language, I believe its Python, but I'm not sure

Tags: python, html, django

I just took a part time job as a web developer and need help identifying some code. They told me it was built in html/css/javascript, but they are using what I believe are python template tags. They are comfortable with me learning a new language, I just want to make sure that I'm learning the correct language.

I've copy and pasted the code into google and stack overflow search bars, again it looks like python/django or possibly jinja 2, but I don't know those languages and want to make sure I'm on the right track. This is just the opening line of the master.master file, which I am also not used to seeing as a master file.

```
`
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="{{ data.Language }}" dir="{% if data.LanguageDetails.IsRtl 
    %}rtl{% else %}ltr{% endif %}">
    <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
    {% block meta %}{% endblock %}
    {% for language in data.Languages %}{% if language.Culture != 
    data.Language %}
    {% assign currentLanguagePrefix = '/' | Append:data.Language | Append: 
     '/' %}
    {% assign thisLanguagePrefix = language.Culture | Append: '/' %}
    <link href="/{{ data.URL | Replace: currentLanguagePrefix, 
    thisLanguagePrefix }}" hreflang="{{ language.Culture }}" rel="alternate">
    {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}`
```

Comment: Looks like https://shopify.github.io/liquid/, but why don't you ask people with more context?

Comment: This does look like Django template syntax, except for the `assign` tag.  But this is just a template -- presumably you also have access to the code behind the template?  That will tell you a lot more.

Comment: @JohnGordon this is just the code in the header of the master.master file. I was trying to avoid sharing the whole file for privacy and also brevity sake. Most of the files begin with:
     `{% extends master.master %}
     {% block title %}{% T About {0} || data.Business.Name %}{% endblock %}
     {% block main %`

Comment: It's certainly a dialect of django template language. It has some tags that does not exist in django or jinja. There's a bunch of template languages with similar syntax: https://medium.com/@i5ar/template-languages-a7b362971cbc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is [Liquid](https://shopify.github.io/liquid/). The syntax is very similar to django template language, because liquid (and jinja, twig, nunjucks) was directly inspired by django.

Liquid has some features that doesn't exist in django template language, for example the  `assign` tag and `append` filter. Here's an example [from the Liquid docs](https://shopify.github.io/liquid/filters/append/):

```
{% assign filename = "/index.html" %}
{{ "website.com" | append: filename }}
```

Liquid is written in Ruby used in many projects, and is ported to other languages (but not to python).

Comment: I went digging around and found that Nexudus considers itself a "white-label solution", when I searched it shows that it is html/css/javascript and that it is "spiced up using dotliquid." So it would appear this is an offshoot of liquid. I don't have any Ruby experience, do I need to get some before I start tinkering with liquid template tags?

Comment: No, that's kinda the point of template languages. You don't need to learn the underlying language etc. You should be able to do plenty by just consulting the Liquid docs. Here's a good place to start: https://github.com/Shopify/liquid/wiki/Liquid-for-Designers

Answer (score 0):

Probably not Jinja2, but instead Django.

In Django method calls work implicitly, while Jinja requires the explicit Python syntax. Thus this Django code:

```
{% for page in user.get_created_pages %}
    ...
{% endfor %}
```

...looks like this in Jinja:

```
{% for page in user.get_created_pages() %}
    ...
{% endfor %}
```

[More examples.](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/2.10/switching/)

Comment: Thank you! That's kind of what I thought. I don't have a background in Python but it's something I've been interested in learning. Should I worry about Django at all or just go Python basics then learning Jinja2?

Comment: Django is used to build web apps. If that is what you are interested in doing with Python than you should learn it also, but I would start with the basics before jumping into Django.

Comment: are you sure this is jinja2 and not the built-in django templating language? It looks more like the latter to me.

Comment: @EdekiOkoh Thank you for the input, but I was hired to update a website and they told me it was just html/css/javascript, but with these jinja2 templates in there I need to learn that as well.

Comment: @MaxFleischman Edeki Okoh's advice is correct. They answer to the question of "Should I learn x programming language?" depends on what you are trying/paid to do. If you aren't building a web app, Django isn't _necessary_, but if you want to become a front end developer it would be a good idea.

Comment: @evamvid I'm not sure whether it's jinja2 or django, there isn't anyone with programming experience working there and I don't have access to whomever built the site. The company uses Nexudus to manage their business, and this comes from the website templates section on Nexudus.

Comment: @AlecB. Thank you, I am trying to identify what language this code is so that I can learn it. I'm interested in Python and Django, but right now I need to keep my focus on fixing this site.

Comment: Actually, @MaxFleischman, it might actually be the Django built-in templating language. Since none of the methods are referred to explicitly, it's more likely that it isn't jinja2

Comment: Thank you @AlecB. I really appreciate the help.